# Development environment in apache that will seamlessly move to production

Tags: html, apache, directory

So my current situation is that I want to set up a folder under my htdocs folder (let's call it company) where I will store all of my company's current content that is used to serve their website. The issue is that the links in the html pages are currently based on root index (/) whereas all of my folders needed for the pages including images, css are in /company. What is the best way to address this issue so that I do not need to change the links in every single html document to development url, then back to production url?

Thanks!

To clarify, all the pages are static html pages, and I use a simple text editor. I am not a web designer, I am just a web developer who needs to quickly edit some my company's web pages to add/edit content and I am looking to do this as quickly as possble. I was hoping for an apache configuration option or something to that effect, but thanks to all for the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making a virtual host in the apache httpd.conf file which would make the document root for files in my /company folder /company instead of / . Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Create a virtual machine on your workstation that mirrors the structure of the server environment. Keep everything oriented towards the server environment. Use separate VMs for different setups.

If you were using PHP you could just set up the paths are config variables.

Comment: When you say create a virtual machine, I am a little unclear as to what you mean. You mean literally install another operating system in something like parallels to use just for this development project? The site is all static html pages, so there is no great way for me to script the correct paths :(

Comment: That's the problem with static sites, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Are these html pages generated by any cms like wordpress, joomla or drupal ? If they are, you could always download a plugin for permalinks that will update all your links.

Also, if you manage your website using dreamweaver.. I know that dreamweaver have some links editing capabilities.

This tutorial may help you depending on how you work :

http://www.thesitewizard.com/dreamweaver/dreamweaver-cs5-tutorial-7.shtml

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I clarified my question a little bit in the original. Thanks anyway!